# How can I pass an anonymous JavaScript object from Java to JavaScript in GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

I'm creating a GWT wrapper round a JavaScript library.  One of the JavaScript functions takes an anonymous object as its argument e.g.:

```
obj.buildTabs({ hide: true, placeholder: 'placeholder' });
```

On the Java side how do I create this type of JavaScript object and pass it to my native implementation?

At the moment, on the Java side I have:

```
public void buildTabs(TabConfiguration config) {
   // ?
}

private native void buildTabs(?) /*-{
        $wnd.NAMESPACE.lib.buildTabs(?);
}-*/;
```

Any pointers appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you exactly know what parameters should be used, you can do the following (remove additional new lines after ::)

```
private native void buildTabs(TabConfiguration config) /*-{
        $wnd.NAMESPACE.lib.buildTabs({hide: 
                config.@com.yournamehere.TabConfiguration::
                getHide()(), 
                placeholder: 
                config.@com.yournamehere.TabConfiguration::
                getPlaceholder()()});
}-*/;
```

a small clip from the [GWT documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideCodingBasics.html):

```
public native void bar(JSNIExample x, String s) /*-{
    // Call instance method instanceFoo() on this
    this.@com.google.gwt.examples.JSNIExample::instanceFoo(Ljava/lang/String;)(s);

    // Call instance method instanceFoo() on x
    x.@com.google.gwt.examples.JSNIExample::instanceFoo(Ljava/lang/String;)(s);

    // Call static method staticFoo()
    @com.google.gwt.examples.JSNIExample::staticFoo(Ljava/lang/String;)(s);

    // Read instance field on this
    var val = this.@com.google.gwt.examples.JSNIExample::myInstanceField;

    // Write instance field on x
    x.@com.google.gwt.examples.JSNIExample::myInstanceField = val + " and stuff";

    // Read static field (no qualifier)
    @com.google.gwt.examples.JSNIExample::myStaticField = val + " and stuff";
  }-*/;
```